# forEach works without passing arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
var arr = [2, 3];

const addNum = (num) => console.log(num + 2); 

arr.forEach(addNum);

Result in the console: 
// 4
// 5
```

In the above code, I used the forEach method and as a callback function, I used the addNum function. But, in the addNum function I didn't pass any arguments and it still works, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because foreach receives a **callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])** so in this case the currentValue is num

Comment: Thanks! I got it, the "current value is num" part really solved it!

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` function has an argument that takes a *function*.

The documentation specifies the signature as:

```
arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])
```

You can give that function however you like. It could be pre-defined, or it could be inline, as in `forEach(function(x) { ... })` or `forEach(x => ...)`.

You have a lot of flexibility in how you call functions like `forEach` as they generally follow the same rules. This is a pattern you'll see a lot of in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])
```

Because `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.